# What are the consequences of marking a method async in C# 5.0?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, c#-5.0

From what I understand in order to use `await` I have to be inside of a method which is marked as `async`. If that's the case, I can use `await` on any `Task<Thing>` to *somewhat synchronously* retrieve the value of the `Task`'s result.

```
Task<bool> task = new Task<bool>(() => false);
task.Start();

int result = await task;
```

To do this I need to be inside of a method marked with `async`.

**What I want to ask here is what exactly is the meaning of `async` and what are the consequences of marking a method with `async`.**

Also, what's the difference between these two?

```
Task<bool> Foo() {
  var task = new Task<bool>(() => false);
  task.Start();
  return task;
}

async Task<bool> Foo2() {
  var task = new Task<bool>(() => false);
  task.Start();
  return await task;
}
```

I can both use them with `await` from inside an `async` method.

```
var res1 = await Foo();
var res2 = await Foo2();
```

Is the only difference that `Foo2` can use `await` in it's body, while `Foo` can't?

Comment: With `async`-`await` you should always use `Task.Run` to create your tasks.

Comment: @PauloMorgado What's the difference from using the constructor?

Comment: it's not usal to instantiate a Task using it's constructor (although possible). Unless you want to create but not start it. As for the difference between `Run` and `StartNew`, please refer to Stephen Toub's blog post: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2011/10/24/10229468.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main purpose of the `async` keyword is to avoid conflicts with code used in prior to C# 5.0 In other words we could say to maintain backword compatiblity.

Prior to C# 5.0 you could have used identifiers/types as `await`

```
void Somemethod()
{
    int await = 5;//identifier
    await myAwait = new await();//type
}
```

Above code is completely valid in prior to C# 5.0(in C# 5.0 also this is valid unless and until you use it in async method), What happens if `await` is added as a `reserved keyword` in c# 5.0? Your code won't compile. and that would be a breaking change.

So to maintain backward compatiblity language designers chosen to make `await` as a contextual keyword. So next question arises `await` is going to be a `contextual keyword` but what is the context here?

Well, there comes the `async` keyword, presence of `async` just enables the `await` keyword. and it makes the compiler to emit `AsyncStateMachineAttribute` to the method as well.

I didn't talk anything about how `async` method is transformed assuming you know that already or that is beyond the point of the question.

Comment: What has .Net 4.5 have to do with this? `await` works in .Net 4.0 too. I think you meant to say C# 5.0 whenever you said .net 4.5.

Comment: @svick How can you make async/await work in .Net 4.0?

Answer (score 3):

It just alerts the compiler that the method may contain await expressions.  Which enables it to do a consistency check on the method return value.  And enables the rewriting logic built into the compiler that makes it transform the method into a hidden class.

If you don't actually use the *await* operator in the method body then this rewriting doesn't need to occur and the *async* keyword isn't needed either.  If you use *async* anyway then you'll get an otherwise benign warning (CS1998) to point out that your code is probably not what you intended to write.  A good diagnostic.

Comment: I'd say it has also another effect: it wraps any returned value in a `Task<T>`.

Comment: @svick So in another words, `Task` is a monad? :P

Comment: @JakubArnold Sure, [you can look at it that way](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2013/04/03/tasks-monads-and-linq.aspx).